# How to define this time complexity?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

Given the problem to calculate the next year that has no duplicated digits on it. I created this code:

```
import math

# Time complexity:
# Space complexity:
def solve(year):
    """ Method to identify the closest year without repeating two digits on it."""
    year_str = str(year)
    if year_str[3] == year_str[0] or year_str[3] == year_str[1] or year_str[3] == year_str[2]:
        year = year + 1
        return solve(year)
    if year_str[2] == year_str[0] or year_str[2] == year_str[1]:
        year = (math.floor(year/10)+1)*10
        return solve(year)
    if year_str[1] == year_str[0]:
        year = (math.floor(year/100)+1)*100
        return solve(year)
    return year

y = int(input())
print(solve(y+1))
```

Not sure if this is the more optimal solution, but I would like to define the time complexity of this solution.

However, I am not sure how to do it in this case.

According to my tests, when it has to process the year 2222 for example, it calls the function "solve" 4 times.

But in cases near the change of decade and century, e.g. 1987 (with result 2013), it calls the function "solve" 8 times.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: You will need a number theoretic approach here. As *n* tends to infinity, how many numbers > n can there be in a row such that they all have some duplicate digit?